# Autofac configuration problems trying to integrate Quartz

Tags: entity-framework, ioc-container, quartz-scheduler, autofac

I am working with the Owned type as found here:  [Strong reference of Autofac 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871987/strong-reference-of-autofac-2/4872949#4872949)

I'm also using Quartz scheduler, MSMQ, and EF.

My config looks as follows.  I've clearly got something wrong as the context that gets injected to the repositories is a different instance than the one given to the service.

```
builder.RegisterType<EmailAllocationJob>();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(JobWrapper<>));

builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().InstancePerOwned<EmailAllocationJob>();
builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().As<IUnitOfWork>(); 

builder.RegisterType<EmailAccountRepository>().As<IEmailAccountRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<EmailMessageRepository>().As<IEmailMessageRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<EmailMessageQueue>().As<IEmailMessageQueue>();

builder.RegisterType<EmailAllocationService>().As<IEmailAllocationService>();
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the configuration fixed.  I'd reckon it's the line:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().As<IUnitOfWork>();
```

What I want to say is something like:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerOwned<EmailAllocationJob>();
```

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it.  Needed the line:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().InstancePerOwned<EmailAllocationJob>()
    .As<IUnitOfWork>().AsSelf();
```

So it seems important that the DataContext features as the generic argument to RegisterType ONCE, and that the method calls to As<>() and AsSelf() are to be daisy chained in a single statement.  Seems obvious now, with a fresh head following yesterday evening.